# Where should I implement specific queries in mvc architecture(spring + hibernate)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm implementing an enterprise application using spring mvc and hibernate. The application architecture is composed by the following layers:

- View
- Controller
- Service
- Domain
- Peristence

The data access is implemented with classic dao pattern and allows CRUD operations + generic queries. Where should I implement specific queries? I guess two solutions:

- implement specific queries in the service layer by creating hibernate criteria and passing it to the persistence layer
- implement specific queries in DAO classes by create a function for each query and call the functions in the service layer.

What should I do? Are there better solutions?

Comment: Creating complex criteria is typically the sort of persistence-related work that you don't want in your service, but in your DAOs. If the DAOs only contain basic methods that the Hibernate session already has, then they aren't really useful.

Comment: I haven't complex criteria but a lot of simple criteria. This means creating a lot of very simple and fine grain functions in DAO classes so I'm wondering if this is the correct approach.

Comment: It is the right approach. That way, your service can concentrate on what it's for: business logic. And you can test it by mocking the DAOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service layer is a **business layer** and there **must not be used** any persistence provider related interfaces and classes (i.e. Hibernate Criteria API). That's a good practice - you can change your persistence provider without touching any line of code in your service layer.

Don't hesitate to go with your second option (implement specific queries in DAO classes).

Alternatively you can use kind of **business dynamic query** pattern which is mix of the **query** and **builder** pattern (like Criteria API). Here is the simple example:

```
interface CarQuery {
    CarQuery model(String model);
    CarQuery color(String color);
    List<CarQuery> execute(); 
}
....
List<Car> cars = carDao.getQuery().model("Jeep").color("green").execute();
....
```

You can implement **HibernateCarQuery** that can use Hibernate Criteria API internally. This surely requires some additional efforts but will not pollute your daos with specific methods if you're planning to use them extensively and need ability to build queries dynamically (typical case is multiple filters on UI pages).

Comment: I would go further and say that your service layer should not have to change if you switched ORM providers (i.e. went from Hibernate to something else) -- only the DAO layer should need to change.

Answer (score 1):

From layered architecture perspective, the sql queries should not be used/declared outside DAO layer. You might have noticed that spring opted to use transaction on service layer since transaction is not the responsibility of DAO and you can also call it as resource leakage/cross cutting concern. Declaring /using sql queries apart from Dao will be considered to be resource leakage/cross cutting concern.

I would like to add something since you touched hibernate and criteria API. When you are using criteria then why should you need separate query? Criteria API is an elegant way to achieve persistence because it is perfect OO approach.

Comment: When I talk about query I mean create Critera for query the DB. I don't use separate query. The point is: should I expose hibernate criteria in the service layer? This avoid me from write a lot of simple functions in DAOs but violate the layers separation.

Comment: I mentioned about resource leak.Kindly understand the answer and come up with questions.. Thanks!

Comment: If you are not bothered about resource leakage/cross cutting concern then go ahead with your approach. but correct way is to implement it in DAO

Answer (score 1):

This:

- implement specific queries in DAO classes by create a function for each query and call the functions in the service layer.

DAO is shorthand for "Data Access Object" and one of the maim reasons to use the DAO pattern is to comply with the "Single Responsibility Principle". If you have some other classes in your code, other than the DAO classes, which handle Data Access, then you are violating the SRP and it becomes a more or less moot point to use the DAO pattern at all.

More importantly, for maintainability purposes, if other developers are going to maintain your code later on, and they see a bunch of DAO classes lying about, they are not going to expect data access to be happening anywhere else.

Your service layer isn't even supposed to have a dependency on Hibernate. Why would you have that? Your service layer should only depend on your domain layer, which in turn depends on your persistence layer, which is where your Hibernate dependency should be,

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have all the queries in the DAO class methods and run them. If you are working on HQL, have all the queries written in the NamedQuery and access it by name at the run time.

Answer (score 0):

I use to create a `GenericDAO` class and an `IDao` interface and all the other DAOs - let's say a 
`ClientDAO` - extends the Generic.

That being said, I create an interface that extends `IDao` (which have the basics methods like `findAll()`, `delete()`, `save()`)

E.g.

### IClient

```
public interface IClient extends IDao { 
   public void findWithWhere(String where);
}
```

### ClientDaoImpl

```
public class ClientDaoImpl extends GenericDao<Client> implements IClient {

  public void findWithWhere(String where) {
   //do custom stuff here
  }
}
```

And then have a ClientDaoImpl object in the Controller (or Service) Layer
That may look a little tiring to do, but, for me, it keeps all the layers well divided and when I have to change a method (maybe receive a new parameter), I simple change the interface to know where I have to implement.

Comment: You could have QUERIES in your Service Layer, but, in order to keep the pattern, I rather create them in the DAO Layer

Comment: My solution is more or less the same as your. The point is that I have a lot of different fine grain queries to implement so I have to implement a lot of simple funtions in DAOs (or a complex parametrized one) and I don't know if this is the right way but it seems it is